# Why can't I access the items of an array after they have been added?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code:

```
var counter = 0;
var Index = {};
rows.forEach(function(element){     
    Index[counter] = element.data;
    counter++;
});
```

And if I do `Console.log(Index)` it's displayed the right way in my console.

But I can't get to the data in this object. Things that don't work:

```
Index[3] //Undefined
Index["3"] //Undefined
Object.keys(Index) //Empty Array
```

The same happens if I use a `Array` and `Array.push()`;

```
Index[3] // Undefined
Index.length // 0
```

Where is my error?

Screenshot from the console:

[image]

Comment: Post the full code, please, so that your problem can be reproduced

Comment: The full code is very long. But I create it like this and do the Console.log right after it. So I guess it should work like this?

Comment: How about the rows, please post the code for that part too.

Comment: Can you put what is in your rows ?

Comment: the rows is an array of objects and I just need the data attribute and it contains just an int value. I put now a screenshot in my question of the Index Array.

Comment: @sirzento Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Guessing an async function

Comment: As others have said it's difficult to work out whats wrong with the information you've provided, however it looks like your attempting to reduce your array down to an object with key being the array index and value being the array value. If so this may work `rows.reduce((accu, cur, i) => Object.defineProperty(accu, i, { value: cur }), {})`. I could also be completely mistaken... Just to add, if that is what your doing its a bit pointles, thats all an Array is anyway. Except now youve lost out on the methods available on the prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `rows` is coming from ajax request and you are doing your calculations before that promise comes. If we have more of that code it would be really nice.